# vsftpd interrupting uploas with error 451

Tags: centos7, ftp, vsftpd

From sometime vsftpd crashes an upload of a client almost everyday. Client uploads usually 4 big files (> 1 GB) and a bunch of smaller ones. At least one of these files, usually a big one, is interrupted with error 451 (towards the end), but I don't really know what this means and from what I've seen on other questions people received this error because of permissions, but this is not the case.
Is there a way to debug this further or to obtain any information that could be useful?

Software is vsftpd version 3.0.2 on centos 7.
What is being logged:

```
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "230 Login successful."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "CWD /mnt/QNAP/ac024/BatchUpload/"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "550 Failed to change directory."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "PASV"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "227 Entering Passive Mode (217,113,213,101,46,90)."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "LIST NOTIZIE OGGI - BL1 (REGISTRATO) - REGIA UNO_20220927055955.MP4"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "150 Here comes the directory listing."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "226 Directory send OK."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "PASV"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "227 Entering Passive Mode (217,113,213,101,45,171)."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "NLST NOTIZIE OGGI - BL1 (REGISTRATO) - REGIA UNO_20220927055955.MP4"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "150 Here comes the directory listing."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "226 Directory send OK."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "TYPE I"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "200 Switching to Binary mode."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "PASV"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "227 Entering Passive Mode (217,113,213,101,44,75)."
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "STOR NOTIZIE OGGI - BL1 (REGISTRATO) - REGIA UNO_20220927055955.MP4"
Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "150 Ok to send data."

Tue Sep 27 06:44:11 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "451 Failure writing to local file."
Tue Sep 27 06:44:11 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "<ip>", "/NOTIZIE OGGI - BL1 (REGISTRATO) - REGIA UNO_20220927055955.MP4", 1199503196 bytes, 12065.67Kbyte/sec
Tue Sep 27 06:44:11 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "<ip>", "QUIT"
Tue Sep 27 06:44:11 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "<ip>", "221 Goodbye."
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log the client make mistake with the directory:

> Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022 [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP command: Client "", "CWD /mnt/QNAP/ac024/BatchUpload/" Tue Sep 27 06:42:34 2022
> [pid 23872] [ac024bu] FTP response: Client "", "**550 Failed to change directory**."

So it upload the files in current directory (usually his home directory) and with high probability fill it. Make sure the target directory `/mnt/QNAP/ac024/BatchUpload/` exist and the user have rights to write there.

Comment: the change of directory is 'inherited' from previous instance of vsftpd, the people uploading files are not able to manage their software very well and still send this command, but file is written in correct directory

Comment: @lunadir, in such case check the size of the filesystem. Also if QNAP offer you check this filesystem (`fsck` command or similar)

Comment: i'm not sysadmin so i can't do it by my initiative, but i will suggest it; anyway there are 2 TB free on 15, so space should not be an issue; i tried uploading 10 GB files to try anyway and no errors

Comment: @lunadir, you can contact your sysadmin to check the things. Also  you can check if the user(s) have quotas defined for these filesystems.

Comment: i checked that beforehand, there are quotes configured (they exist, but they are warnings in our backend, they are set in the os)

Comment: @lunadir, that's the idea, when you have quota in you QNAP filesystem user is limited in sense of diskspace in this filesystem. And for sure there are also hard limits (if quotas are set)

Comment: sorry i made a mistake writing and can't edit the post, there are **no** quotes configured, they are managed in a soft way by our software (we don't put hard limits, it's fine if clients go a little overboard)

Comment: @lunadir, what is the filesystem of `/mnt/QNAP/ac024/BatchUpload` and do you have in this filesystem many small files?

Comment: it's xfs, since it's a storage for media files there are few big files; there are no folders with 1 million files if that's what you are asking, whole nas has less that 1 million files even